# Custom ContentDialog in WinUI 3

Tags: xaml, user-interface, modal-dialog, winui-3, contentdialog

In my program I have a TabControl with multiple tabs and in each tab there could be a dialog that the user may open at any time. I use the dialogs to allow the user to enter stuff into a database. I wish to replicate the look and functionality of the original ContentDialog but not be limited to only having 1 open at a time.

The idea would be something along the lines of a panel that floats over the rest of the tab control item(but not the whole app window) and denies interaction with anything in that tab control  below it (but not the whole program) until closed.

The current limitations on ContentDialog's according to Microsoft:

> "There can only be one ContentDialog open per thread at a time. Attempting to open two ContentDialogs will throw an exception, even if they are attempting to open in separate app windows."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog?view=windows-app-sdk-1.4

What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: There's nothing builtin. You can create as many Windows as you want though, and they are not modal, but you'll have to handle all moves, positioning, focus, etc. It's possible that you'll have to use some interop to adjust all that to your needs.

Comment: @SimonMourier would it be possible to make some kind of overlay say a panel with a semi transparent background and some controls that sits on top of the other stuff and therefore is sort of like a modal?

Comment: With windows (and maybe some added interop code) it's probably possible yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve what you are trying to do without the `ContentDialog` is to show a layer on top of your tab content and on top of that layer show what you wanted to show on the `ContentDialog`.

For example:

```xml
<TabView>
    <TabView.TabItems>
        <TabViewItem
            VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
            Header="Tab #1">
            <Grid>
                <Grid
                    x:Name="ContentPanel"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Button
                        Click="ShowMessageButton_Click"
                        Content="Show message" />
                </Grid>

                <StackPanel
                    x:Name="MessageBasePanel"
                    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                    Opacity="0.5"
                    Visibility="Collapsed" />
                <StackPanel
                    x:Name="MessagePanel"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Visibility="Collapsed">
                    <TextBlock Text="Some message." />
                    <Button
                        Click="CloseMessageButton_Click"
                        Content="Close" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>

        </TabViewItem>
        <TabViewItem Header="PowerShell">
            <TabViewItem.IconSource>
                <BitmapIconSource
                    ShowAsMonochrome="False"
                    UriSource="/Assets/TabViewIcons/powershell.png" />
            </TabViewItem.IconSource>
        </TabViewItem>
        <TabViewItem Header="Windows Subsystem for Linux">
            <TabViewItem.IconSource>
                <BitmapIconSource
                    ShowAsMonochrome="False"
                    UriSource="/Assets/TabViewIcons/linux.png" />
            </TabViewItem.IconSource>
        </TabViewItem>
    </TabView.TabItems>
</TabView>
```

```cs
private void ShowMessageButton_Click(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.MessageBasePanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    this.MessagePanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}

private void CloseMessageButton_Click(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.MessageBasePanel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    this.MessagePanel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```